# How to iterate a list & counter ++ in a loop in Sightly(HTL)

Tags: sightly

how to achieve this condition in sightly HTL.
I tried but I couldn't able to implement this condition.
Pls help me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itemList.odd` and `itemList.even` with `data-sly-test` to conditionally render the divs. See https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#226-list!